# Implementing rdt 1.0 (reliable data transfer) in java, rtd_send(packet)

Tags: java, networking, symbols, packet, rtd

So for a project I have to implement rdt in java using a simulator that has already been coded for me, I just have to do the sender and receiver classes (entities). [This is a diagram of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEJQ7.png) 
But whenever I try udt_send(packet) or rdt_send(packet) I get an error 'cannot find symbol' for rtd and utd. I presumed it was a pre-set thing in java but evidently not, any ideas of what I'm supposed to do with this or how the rtd or utd is meant to work? Thanks guys.

p.s. Only unidirectional transfer of data is required.

Comment: Did you try something yourself? Please make sure you try something first and then post it here.

Comment: Well I tried to send the packet into the network to arrive at the other host via udtsend(packet); but get the cannot find symbol problem